# what's the different between anonymouse function wrapper and the new function wrapper in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I saw some people wrap the code in new function(){} like

```
new function(){
   var app= angular.module('app',[])
   app.controller('ctrl',function(){});
};
```

It worked, but what's the different from (function(){})()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things are different:

1. It creates an object which, in your example, isn't used for anything and is available for garbage collection immediately after the function returns.
2. It changes the value of `this` within the function:

   - In your `new` example, `this` refers to the object from #1
   - In your second example (an IIFE), `this` is either `undefined` (in strict mode) or a reference to the global object (in loose mode)

If you're not going to use the object that `new` creates, there's no point to the `new` form; it's just a style choice.

Answer (score 2):

`new` will return you an instance, it works as a construtor.
`(function(){})();` will simply run a function just once as you declare it, this is also known as IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression.

But your example with `new` is not correct, as you would need to assign your data to `this` in order for something to be stored in the instance you are building. Ex:

```
var obj = new function(){
  this.app= angular.module('app',[])
  this.app.controller('ctrl',function(){});
};

// Now you can use obj.app
```

Comment: *"But your example with new is not correct"* It's fine. Some people use that form without actually using the object `new` creates. I'm not a fan, but some people prefer it for stylistic reasons. Thankfully it's relatively rare.